# In centrioles, what type of fibers connect the triplet microtubules?

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-structure

In a centriole, each "arm" (a triplet microtubule) is attached from its A-tubule to the C-tubule of the adjacent arm. What is the type of fiber that connects each arm ("connecting fibrils" in the image below)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Winey M, O'Toole E. 2014. Centriole structure. Phil Trans R Soc B 369:20130457](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4113101/)

> Cross-sectional images of centrioles and basal bodies show a linker between the A- and C-tubules in many different organisms... **Surprisingly, candidate molecules serving as constituents of these linkers have not yet been identified.**

That's as of 2014. I don't have the time right now, but I'll try at some point to find if there are more recent developments.